# Jenkins hangs the build when starting JBoss server

Tags: ant, jboss, jenkins

I am using Ant to start/stop our JBoss server in Jenkins. The JBoss server starts fine in Jenkins, but the build never finishes even though the server has started. Is it possible to define in Ant or in Jenkins a way to overcome this? I.e. is it possible in Jenkins to overcome this, or is it possible in Ant to somehow start the server "in background" so that when Jenkins has executed the Ant task it immediately goes to next step in the build (I can manually define a sleep in Jenkins to wait for the server to start)?

Comment: post relevant build.xml content

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ant, you could explore [JBoss Management Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JBoss+Management+Plugin)